# Summing each array inside list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

I have a list of arrays generated from another function:

```
testGroup = [array([18]), array([], dtype=int64), array([56, 75, 55, 55]), array([32])]
```

I'd like to return the sum of each individual array in the list, with the empty ones returning as zero

I've tried using numpy, as per the documentation:

```
np.sum([[0, 1], [0, 5]], axis=1)
array([1, 5])np.sum([[0, 1], [0, 5]], axis=1)
array([1, 5])
```

But when I try `np.sum(testGroup, axis=1)` I get an axis error as I suppose the empty arrays have a dimension less than one?

I've also tried summing it directly `arraySum = sum(testGroup)` but get a ValueError

Any ideas on how to achieve a sum of the arrays inside the
`testGroup` list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`testGroup` is a plain python list, that happens to contain `numpy.array` elements. Instead you can use a list comprehension

```
>>> [np.sum(a) for a in testGroup]
[18, 0, 241, 32]
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked

Answer (score 1):

Try
`list(map(np.sum, testGroup))`
it gives

```
[18, 0, 241, 32]
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate you taking the time to help me out

Answer (score 1):

You might use so-called *list-comprehension* to apply function to each element of list as follow

```
import numpy as np
testGroup = [np.array([18]), np.array([], dtype=np.int64), np.array([56, 75, 55, 55]), np.array([32])]
totals = [np.sum(i) for i in testGroup]
print(totals)
```

output

```
[18, 0, 241, 32]
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate you taking the time to help me out